# How do I keep my Django REST API stateless without cookie and sessions when deployed in lambda with Cognito

Tags: lambda, django-rest-framework

I am deploying django REST APIs to AWS Lambda using Zappa. for authentication, I would like to use JWT tokens between my angular web app, mobile app and django REST APIs. How do I keep my django REST APIs stateless without any sessions or cookies?

Comment: try https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication

Comment: show us sample of your code may be we can understand what you are trying to achive

Answer (score 1):

I'm not django developer but authentication for stateless app should have 2 part.

1. develop new authentication API, return JWT token to client upon success login. This JWT token may contain user profile in its body (base64-encoded) to feed your screen. This token is generated using a secret key defined in your Django backend (so you need to protect this secret)
2. every single call from your Angular app requires to pass along JWT token as Authorization header. Django backend have to check for this JWT token, validate the JWT header & payload, return relevant data for this user (by extracting user profile from JWT body). By validating the jwt header, you would know that the token is generated by your backend application but not other.
   (use Spring Security Filter if Java or in NodeJS can be done with middleware)